# changing forEach into for loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, html-table

Javascript beginner here, trying to learn by coding, at the moment i'm trying to learn 'forEach' and 'for', here i have a code where it is working with 'forEach' i'm trying to change it into 'for loop', like this(dont know if i'm doing right here ?) if possibly somebody could write separate 'for loops' for this ? would be good for new programmers.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arvvoja.length; i++) { 
  option.textContent += dataa[i][arvvoja] + " "; 
});
```

without any success, here is my code :

```js
let animals 
let animalCols = ['Animal', 'Animal 2'] 
let peopleCols = ['Person', 'Person 2'] 
 
function myFunction() { 
  paivitys(animals, animalCols) 
} 
 
function paivitys(dataa, arvvoja) { 
  console.log(dataa); 
  //---- 
  if (dataa.hasOwnProperty("animal")) { 
    document.getElementById("1name").innerHTML = dataa.animal; 
  } else { 
    document.getElementById("1name").innerHTML = dataa.person; 
  } 
  //----   
  if (dataa.hasOwnProperty("animal2")) { 
    document.getElementById("2name").innerHTML = dataa.animal2; 
  } else { 
    document.getElementById("2name").innerHTML = dataa.person2; 
     
  } 
 
  document.getElementById("1name1").innerHTML = arvvoja[0]; 
  document.getElementById("2name1").innerHTML = arvvoja[1]; 
 
  //-----  
  document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = dataa.id; 
} 
 
function paivitaselekt(dataa, arvvoja) { 
  for (var i = 0; i < dataa.length; i++) { 
    var valitse = document.getElementById("Select"); 
    var option = document.createElement("option"); 
    arvvoja.forEach((value) => { 
      option.textContent += dataa[i][value] + " "; 
    }); 
    valitse.appendChild(option); 
  } 
} 
 
animals = { 
  "animal": "tiger", 
  "animal2": "lion", 
  "id": "54321", 
  "dole": { 
    "Key": "fhd699f" 
  } 
} 
 
paivitys(animals, animalCols); 
let kokoarray; 
 
people = [{ 
    "person": "kaka", 
    "person2": "julle", 
    "id": "9874", 
  }, 
  { 
    "person": "Ronaldo", 
    "person2": "jussi", 
    "id": "65555", 
  } 
] 
kokoarray = people; 
paivitaselekt(kokoarray, ["person", "id"]); 
 
document.getElementById("Select").addEventListener("change", function(event) { 
  const otettutunnsite = event.target.value.split(" ")[1]; 
  const otettutieto = kokoarray.filter((dataa) => dataa.id === otettutunnsite)[0]; 
  paivitys(otettutieto, peopleCols); 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> 
    <link 
      rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    /> 
    <link 
      rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" 
      integrity="sha384UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" 
      crossorigin="anonymous" 
    /> 
    <style> 
 
    </style> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
  
<div class=""> 
  <table class="table "> 
    <thead> 
      <tr> 
        <th   id="1name1" class="table-success">Animal</th> 
        <th   id="2name1" class="table-success">Animal</th> 
        <th   class="table-success">id</th> 
      </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
      <th id="1name"></th> 
      <th id="2name"></th> 
      <th id="id"></th> 
    </tbody> 
  </table> 
 
  <select id="Select" ></select> 
  <button onclick="myFunction()">backtozero</button> 
</div> </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: the answer is good but need separate 'for loops' out of each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different variable in the inner loop:

```
var i, j;
for (i = 0; i < dataa.length; i++) { 
    var valitse = document.getElementById("Select"); 
    var option = document.createElement("option"); 
    for (j = 0; j < arvvoja.length; j++) { 
       option.textContent += dataa[i][arvvoja[j]] + " "; 
    } 
    valitse.appendChild(option); 
}
```

Comment: thank you, could this be done in some other easier way ? now there is two 'for loops', could i use one 'for loop' or something other easier way ?

Comment: @waleedd32 Well that was not your original question, please open a new one for the same

Comment: that wouldnt be proper question and maybe i would get downvoted ?

Comment: @waleedd32 You can ask it on this platform specifically for code improvements and suggestions https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Be sure to accept this answer :)

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240745/suggestion-for-improving-this-code-to-be-much-readable-and-easy-for-beginners

Comment: Yes ok, you will get help there now that the question is posted

Comment: i have never posted there before, is it same as here ?

Comment: Don't use `var` to declare variables in a loop header. Use `let` which will scope the declaration to the loop or declare the `var` at the top level of the function, because that's where it is in scope

Comment: @waleedd32 Yes pretty much the same

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava  could you make them outside each other i mean now it is for loop inside for loop could you make them separate ?

Comment: @waleedd32 Your question was (still is) about converting forEach to a for loop and you got an answer for that exactly. Now if you have new queries you should ask a new question. Forget about downvotes, its about getting an answer to your question. Think about it this way, if your question says something and you want to ask something else, it is a waste of time for both you and people who are answering. Doesn't make sense to comment on the same question days later with a new requirement.

Comment: @waleedd32 Ask a new question if you can, and please don't tag me in more comments

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava thanks for comment and sorry disturbing, you are right just needed this to be separate for loops, i thought it would be easier to just edit this question